# Some byte comparison works only if I log the values first in Java

Tags: java

I have a super weird problem.

```
public enum MyCmd {
  CMD_UP((byte) 0x80),
  CMD_DOWN((byte) 0x81);
  UNKNOWN((byte) 0xFF);

  public static MyCmd getCmd(byte b) {
    for (MyCmd cmd : MyCmd.values()) {
      if (cmd == b)
        return cmd;
    }
    return UNKNOWN;
  }
}

void f(byte b) {
    _logger.debug("in:" + b);  // remove or not ?
    MyCmd cmd = MyCmd.getCmd(b);
    switch (cmd) {
        CMD_UP: _logger.debug("up"); break;
        CMD_DOWN: _logger.debug("down"); break;
        default:  _logger.debug("unknown"); break;
    }
}


// with log
f((byte)(0x80))
  in: -127
  up

// without log
f((byte)(0x80))
  unknown
```

When f is called with b=-127, it goes to the "unknown" case. But if I log b before entering the switch, then things are ok. Any idea ?

One thing that I was thinking of : 0x80 is 128 and with bytes I don't know where it goes and if there is a conflict with 0xFF and depending on the log the compiler does one thing or another ?

Comment: Which version of Java is that?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could reproduce this. Please try to provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. That code shouldn't even compile as far as I can tell, given that `if (cmd == b)` is comparing a `MyCmd` with a `byte`... and you haven't even provided a `MyCmd(byte)` constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am quite uncomfortable as you say because I can't reproduce the problem very specifically. I am asking for experience here with this kind of thing.

Comment: @Thomas: Well you could start with code that compiles. But I suspect that basically you were running a broken version of the code that happened to have logging in, then you fixed a bug at the same time as you removed the logging. Until we've got any evidence that that's not the case, it's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: @Thomas the code you are showing is far from being compilable - there are missing `case` statements, bogus `;` where there should be a `,` and so forth. What happens when you replace the logger output with `System.err.println`?. Also, when you pass `0x80` to `f`, you say it logs `-127`, but `0x80` is `-128`

Comment: I think you might be confusing things with the different byte values being passed in. Are you sure you are passing in the correct byte value? 0x80 is -128. 0x81 is -127. 0xFF is -1. The switch is missing the UNKNOWN case and the default case is to print unknown. This code doesn't mean that it has encountered 0xFF because it never looks for it. Add a case for UNKNOWN.

Comment: I didn't give the full code indeed (bytes come from the network, the enum is 100 constants, ...), I was not looking from a specific answer to this piece of code but for a general answer about what could go wrong with the compiler

Comment: The problem is real, it is just pretty complicated to come up with a few lines of code that reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

This won't do what you expect:

```
if (cmd == b)
```

This compares an `enum` with a `byte` -> `getCmd()` will always return `UNKNOWN`.

The logging line shouldn't have any effect on the result. I suggest to run the code with a debugger to make sure it behaves as you expect.

There is a very, very small chance that you found a compiler or VM bug. Try the latest version of Java just to rule that out.

Comment: I give you that my code doesn't compile, it was more or less pseudo code. But the problem is real. Even worse : I removed the logging, the program works find, and 5 minutes later things start to not work normally. I have no idea what could go wrong

Comment: Is that the only application which has problems? Did you run a memory test on the machine? Did you try with a more recent version of Java?